# Using filter to show all objects except the one I am clicking on

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I am trying to setup a "remove from cart" button but I ran into some issues. I am having a hard time explaining what I mean, but I will do my best.

So pretty much, my goal is to filter out the product from the cart that the user is clicking on, I am doing this by targeting the ID. Every product has one. So I did this:

```
let id = e.currentTarget.getAttribute("itemid");

const clonedCartItems = JSON.parse(JSON.stringify(cartItems));

console.log(clonedCartItems);

let newCart = clonedCartItems.filter(
  (ele, ind) => ind === clonedCartItems.findIndex((elem) => elem.id !== id)
);

console.log(newCart);
```

But the issue I am having is that I currently have 3 items in the cart. But if I remove one, the other two should console log. But only one of them is logging, I am guessing I would need a loop somewhere? I am just unsure how I should tackle the problem.

If you need me to explain better, let me know and I will do my best!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Can you not just do:

```js
let newCart = clonedCartItems.filter(
  (elem) => elem.id !== id
);
```

The filter method just requires a callback which needs to return a Boolean, if true the element should be kept or discarded otherwise.

You need to return `elem.id !== id` because this will be true for all items except for which the `id == elem.id`

Doc referenced by @hellogoodnight
https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/filter

Comment: Yea it seems I can. Thank you! :)

Comment: No Problem! Just try this and see if it suits your needs

Comment: Will do! Not really following along what it does tho? Or what kind of difference it does from what I had.

Comment: Check out the docs for filter here: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/filter

Comment: @simonsjöö I've edited the answer with some explanation. Hope it helps! you can still ask for more clarification if you need

Answer (score 0):

Changing your code to the below code should work. The `filter` function gives you all the filtered elements. You are using `find` inside `filter` which is not required at all. Also, the find function returns only the first element it finds.

```
let id = e.currentTarget.getAttribute("itemid");

const clonedCartItems = JSON.parse(JSON.stringify(cartItems));

console.log(clonedCartItems);

let newCart = clonedCartItems.filter(ele => ele.id !== id);

console.log(newCart);
```